# Adding alias for public IP hosted by azure dns services

Tags: azure, dns

I have VM for development in Azure w/ azure provided static public IP address. DNS name label for public IP is lets say "aaa". It is assigned to VM and a web site hosted in this VM is accessible as http:\\**aaa**.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com w/o any issues.

However, I need a second web site, which again will be hosted in same VM and needs to be accessible as http:\\**bbb**.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com

Azure portal provides a page to add an alias for the public IP. However when you try to add bbb as an alias, next page requires a DNS zone to be entered. I tried to create and use a made up DNS zone like mydnszone.com to bypass that requirement but now bbb becomes an "A" record under mydnszone.com
Adding eastus.cloudapp.azure.com as a DNS zone is not possibility since I can not see this zone anywhere and no control over it.

In summary how can make **aaa** and **bbb** to point to same public IP address in Azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, it's not possible to make `aaa` and `bbb` to point to same public IP address in Azure. You have to use two Public IP addresses for it.

You may consider adding two NICs to the Azure VM. Each NIC has a private IP address and a public IP address assigned by Azure. Each public IP address will have a Azure provided FQDN like `aaa.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com`. See [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/multiple-nics?toc=/azure/virtual-network/toc.json)t for more details.

Alternatively, If you just want to map two different DNS names to two different websites hosting on the same Azure VM. You can [add an extra public IP address](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-multiple-ip-addresses-portal#associate-the-public-ip-address-resource-to-a-new-ip-configuration) to the same Azure NIC and [add IP addresses to your VM OS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-multiple-ip-addresses-portal#os-config). Then you can access your Azure VM via these two public IP address simultaneously.

If so, you can add two `A` records to map to two public IP addresses in your own DNS zone.

```
aaa.domain.com---public IP address1
bbb.domain.com---public IP address2
```